# How to hang load from ceiling I-beam joists behind drywall?

Tags: ceiling, joists, hanging

I'm looking to attach [rock rings](http://www.elementalfitnesslab.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/RockRings2.jpg) to my garage ceiling. I've found similar posts, but in each one, they have a seemingly critical difference from my setup:

- I don't have access to above the joist because my living room is above my garage ([here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58831/how-to-hang-a-chair-from-the-ceiling-joists-with-attic-access)).
- I have I-beams, not 2x8s ([here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18525/can-i-hang-a-hammock-from-basement-joists), and seemingly [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/35678/what-is-the-best-way-to-hang-a-heavy-dynamic-weight-from-a-flat-ceiling-with-joi)).
- I have drywall covering my I-beams ([here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25135/how-should-i-attach-a-chin-up-bar-to-floor-joists)) but would prefer to leave it.

I do like bcworkz's [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/35684/27165) but I'm not sure if this is something I can do with I-beams. I would think that lag bolting along an I-beam would be bad due to its thin profile. Perhaps this concept could be adapted with opposing angled bolts to better catch the beam?

Are there other options/variants for attaching to I-beams behind drywall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the look, I'd suggest a 2x6 run perpendicular to your joists. Ideally, you'd get 3 joists (so a 2x6 slightly longer than 4', assuming you've got 16" spacing) with at least 2 good 3.5" #10 screws each. (Since these are pretty big screws, you'll want to drill pilot and clearance holes.) To attach the rock rings, use 6/7mm -ish cord through holes you've drilled in the 2x6. (If you don't want to dent the drywall, just chisel a small channel across the top of the holes.)

Comment: I don't mind the look at all, and that's similar to what I was thinking. Where exactly am I aiming for with the screws? Right threw the middle of the I-beam? I assume attaching it to the top and bottom bits of the beam (not sure what that's called) is less sturdy?

Comment: Aim for the middle of the flange (bottom/top bit). If you hit the web (upright section in the middle of the i-beam), it won't hurt. If you're too far off the middle, you run the risk of losing screw strength because of splitting.

Comment: I'd use a few more screws than that, or lags if I was doing it for someone else.

Comment: Lags are totally doable, but I was curious how to accurately hit the middle of the I-beam with a lag, or am I still just aiming for the flange with the lag?

Comment: Whether lags or screws, just aim for the middle of the flange. Generally speaking, there's no holding power in the web, so don't feel like you need to bury a fastener in it.