# Hanging a punch bag from engineered joists

Tags: garage, joists

I have the I-joists. I’m not sure how I will achieve it on this style joist. The joists are in my integrated garage but have a bedroom above. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Then make the file smaller or take another picture. We need to see what you see.

Comment: Or this? [How to hang load from ceiling I-beam joists behind drywall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/how-to-hang-load-from-ceiling-i-beam-joists-behind-drywall)